# RACSubject created on dispatch_queue sendComplete doesn't make it to merged signal

Tags: objective-c, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-cocoa

When in a dispatch_async block running on the DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT gcd queue: I create two RACSubject objects, use RACSignal merge: and then subscribe complete.  Then, for the purposes of this test (and to replicate the scenario in my actual code), I send sendComplete on both of them.  The merged signal completion subscription never fires.  I attached two completion subscriptions to the subjects independently, those do fire.  If I do this same test on the main thread instead of the gcd queue then it works as expected.

Is there a way to make this work or am I going to have to refactor to get all of my subjects on the main thread?

```
#import <ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h>

@interface rac_signal_testTests: SenTestCase
@end

@implementation rac_signal_testTests

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    // Set-up code here.
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Tear-down code here.

    [super tearDown];
}

-(void)test_merged_subjects_will_complete_on_main_thread{
    RACSubject *subject1 = [[RACSubject subject] setNameWithFormat:@"subject1"];
    RACSubject *subject2 = [[RACSubject subject] setNameWithFormat:@"subject2"];

    RACSignal *merged = [RACSignal merge:@[subject1, subject2]];

    __block BOOL completed_fired = NO;

    [merged subscribeCompleted:^{
        completed_fired = YES;
    }];

    [subject1 sendNext:@"1"];
    [subject2 sendNext:@"2"];

    [subject1 sendCompleted];
    [subject2 sendCompleted];

    STAssertTrue(completed_fired, nil);
}

//test proving that throttling isn't breaking the merged signal (initial hypothesis).
-(void)test_merged_subjects_will_complete_if_one_of_them_has_a_throttled_subscriber_on_main_thread{
    RACSubject *subject1 = [[RACSubject subject] setNameWithFormat:@"subject1"];
    RACSubject *subject2 = [[RACSubject subject] setNameWithFormat:@"subject2"];

    __block NSString * hit_subject2_next = nil;
    [[subject2 throttle:.5] subscribeNext:^(NSString *value){
        hit_subject2_next = value;
    }];

    RACSignal *merged = [RACSignal merge:@[subject1, subject2]];

    __block BOOL completed_fired = NO;

    [merged subscribeCompleted:^{
        completed_fired = YES;
    }];

    [subject2 sendNext:@"2"];
    [subject2 sendCompleted];
    [subject1 sendCompleted];
    STAssertEqualObjects(@"2", hit_subject2_next, nil);
    STAssertTrue(completed_fired, nil);
}

-(void)test_merged_subjects_will_complete_if_on_gcd_queue{
    __block BOOL complete = NO;

    dispatch_queue_t global_default_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(global_default_queue, ^{
        RACSubject *subject1 = [[RACSubject subject] setNameWithFormat:@"subject1"];
        RACSubject *subject2 = [[RACSubject subject] setNameWithFormat:@"subject2"];

        __block NSString * hit_subject2_next = nil;

        RACScheduler *global_default_scheduler = [RACScheduler schedulerWithQueue:global_default_queue name:@"com.test.global_default"];

        RACSignal *sig1 = [subject1 deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler];
        RACSignal *sig2 = [subject2 deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler];

        [sig2    subscribeNext:^(NSString *value){
            hit_subject2_next = value;
        }];

        [sig2 subscribeCompleted:^{
            NSLog(@"hit sig2 complete");
        }];

        [sig1 subscribeCompleted:^{
            NSLog(@"hit sig1 complete");
        }];

        RACSignal *merged = [[RACSignal merge:@[sig1, sig2]] deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler];

        [merged subscribeCompleted:^{
            complete = YES;
        }];

        [subject2 sendNext:@"2"];
//        if we dispatch the send complete calls to the main queue then this code works but that seems like it shoul be unnecessary.
//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [subject1 sendCompleted];
            [subject2 sendCompleted];
//        });
    });

    NSDate *startTime = NSDate.date;
    do{
        [NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:.5]];
    }while(!complete && [NSDate.date timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime] <= 10.0);

    STAssertTrue(complete, nil);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So this is a fairly shitty case, caused by the interaction of GCD and RAC. Strictly speaking, there's no bug. But it **is** surprising and weird. We talk about this requirement in the design guidelines at https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/1bd47736f306befab64859602dbdea18f7f9a3f6/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md#subscription-will-always-occur-on-a-scheduler.

The key is that **subscription must always happen on a known scheduler**. This is a requirement that RAC enforces internally. If you're just using plain old GCD, there is no known scheduler so RAC has to send the subscription off to a scheduler asynchronously.

So to go to your test:

```
[merged subscribeCompleted:^{
    complete = YES;
}];
```

The actual subscription happens asynchronously because there is no known scheduler. The subscription ends up happening **after** the `-sendCompleted` calls and it misses them entirely. It's really a race condition, but realistically you're probably never going to see it succeed.

The fix is to use `RACScheduler`s instead of GCD if possible. If you need to use a specific GCD queue, you can use `RACTargetQueueScheduler`. For example, a working, simplified version of your test:

```
-(void)test_merged_subjects_will_complete_if_on_gcd_queue{
    __block BOOL complete = NO;

    dispatch_queue_t global_default_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    RACScheduler *scheduler = [[RACTargetQueueScheduler alloc] initWithName:@"testScheduler" targetQueue:global_default_queue];
    [scheduler schedule:^{
        RACSubject *subject1 = [[RACSubject subject] setNameWithFormat:@"subject1"];
        RACSubject *subject2 = [[RACSubject subject] setNameWithFormat:@"subject2"];

        RACSignal *merged = [RACSignal merge:@[subject1, subject2]];

        [merged subscribeCompleted:^{
            complete = YES;
        }];

        [subject1 sendCompleted];
        [subject2 sendCompleted];
    }];

    NSDate *startTime = NSDate.date;
    do{
        [NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:.5]];
    }while(!complete && [NSDate.date timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime] <= 10.0);

    STAssertTrue(complete, nil);
}
```

Since the subscription happens from within a scheduler, the `subscribeCompleted:` is done synchronously, gets the completed events, and everything behaves as you'd expect.

If you don't need to use a specific GCD queue and just want it done on a non-main queue, then do something like:

```
[[RACScheduler scheduler] schedule:^{
    RACSubject *subject1 = [[RACSubject subject] setNameWithFormat:@"subject1"];
    RACSubject *subject2 = [[RACSubject subject] setNameWithFormat:@"subject2"];

    RACSignal *merged = [RACSignal merge:@[subject1, subject2]];

    [merged subscribeCompleted:^{
        complete = YES;
    }];

    [subject1 sendCompleted];
    [subject2 sendCompleted];
}];
```

I hope that clarifies what you're seeing. Let me know if I need to re-word something.

Comment: Why do you use `RACReplaySubject` where OP uses `RACSubject`?

Comment: Sorry, that was just leftover from some other testing. Fixed!

Comment: No problem; Just making sure that wasn't important to the solution.